# "No such interface 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties' on object at path /"AND“The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?"

Tags: qt, x11, dbus

I am running a Qt5 GUI application on an arm platform with `xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 800x600x24" path-to-my-app &` on Ubuntu.
Most of the time it runs fine, but sometimes the app would crash with error log below:

> No such interface 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties' on object at path /
>   The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?

And eth0 would also lose its IP, there is no `inet addr` section in `ifconfig` result.

In my opinion, these 3 things (dbus, X11 and eth0 losing its IP) are not related. So I don't know where to begin to debug or solve this. Any help will be appreciated.